# Batch script for new instances of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script which can call and run a MATLAB script in the following manner:

```
matlab -r plotFunction(a,b); quit %here, a=1:10 and b=1:10 
matlab -r plotFunction(a,b); quit %in 2nd instance a=11:20, b=11:20
matlab -r plotFunction(a,b); quit %in 3rd instance a=21:30, b=21:30 
and so on.
```

That is, each time a new instance of MATLAB opens up, calls the function plotFunction which performs plotting a 100 times and then the program (MATLAB) quits. Subsequent to this, another instance of the program opens, performs plotting a 100 times again (corresponding to a=11:20 and b=11:20) and quits again. And so forth. How to put this in a loop?

Comment: More importantly, which operating system are you using?  Less importantly, which version of MATLAB?

Comment: Why don't you write a MATLAB script to the all the looping and plotting? It might help if you explain why you need to do this in a batch script.

Comment: OS is windows: One batch running on XP, one on Win 8, one on Win 10, one on Server 2012 and one on Win 7. MATLAB version is 2015b.

Comment: Take a look at the `for /L` command (type `for /?` in command prompt to see details); and also `set /A` for the arithmetic operations...

Answer (score 1):

The [batch_job](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44077-batch-job) toolbox does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables defined in the Windows command prompt to MATLAB line this:

```
set AMIN='1'
set BMIN='1'
set AMAX='10'
set BMAX='10'
matlab -r "disp(str2double(%AMIN%):str2double(%AMAX%)),disp(str2double(%BMIN%):str2double(%BMAX%)); input('press a key to quit'); quit"
```

Edit:

This can be improved like this,

```
set AMIN=1
set BMIN=1
set AMAX=10
set BMAX=10
set MATPROG=^
arange=(%AMIN%:%AMAX%),^
brange=(%BMIN%:%BMAX%),^
[x,y]=meshgrid(arange,brange),^
aplusb=x+y,^
plot3(x,y,aplusb),^
input('press a key to quit'),^
quit
matlab -r "%MATPROG%"
```

Note that ^ is the batch file line continuation character.

This change will make it easier to convert to loops in the batch file, although I don't understand why you don't create the loops in a MATLAB function and call that instead to keep the batch files as simple as possible.

Comment: Suppose the function is a simple addition: 'function aPlusb=sumFunction(a,b)

aPlusb=a+b;' The first instance has to call the function (sumFunction) a 100 times corresponding to a=1:10 and b=1:10 - how to incorporate this?

Comment: Do you want the loop in the batch file. If so, why? It is much easier in MATLAB. See for example [meshgrid](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html?refresh=true). Otherwise there's lot of information on looping in batch files if you search, like [this](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).